# Vaadin 7 - Requested resource not found

Tags: java, css, tomcat, filesystems, vaadin

Everything was fine untill this morning. Here is what I found when I ran my application on Tomcat server:

`INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/connect/styles.css] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.`

The project is on a SVN and it works fine in everyone else's pc! I deleted the whole ecplise, deleted cache and stuff... but still couldn't make to solve this issue!

Why does it not load this damn .css??

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the file `styles.css` exist in the path `/VAADIN/themes/connect/styles.css`?
If not, you can always compile your themes with `mvn vaadin:compile-theme`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven try to run **mvn clean install** to compile the widgetset. If you don't want to use command line, right click in your proyect, **Run As > Maven install.**

If you are not using Maven, open your widgetset file and click in the "gear" symbol in the eclipse menu.